# Generate code coverage for integration tests

Tags: python-3.x, coverage.py

In the ML model which uses python3.6, flask restful, gunicorn (wsgi), nginx and docker, I do not have good unit test coverage but cover almost all scenarios in my integration and regression tests by invoking REST Api developed using flask restful. REST API is deployed into container.

I generated code coverage report using `coverage` i.e. https://pypi.org/project/coverage/ and the report is generated based on my unit tests. But, I also need to see if there is a way to get code coverage using integration and regression tests as well. Since API is deployed into a container, I am not sure how I can get code coverage using integration and regression tests because I invoke REST APIs for the same.

Please let me know if someone has solved this problem already ?

Comment: Did you find any way to achieve this? I am trying the same thing and not able to figure out a way to do it.